# SQLite limit different column then order results

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have a table of a few hundred names and ages.  I want to query the 100 youngest people like

```
SELECT name, age FROM people ORDER BY age ASC LIMIT 100
```

But what if I wanted the results to come back sorted by name?  Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is probably wrong here, but it is something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT name, age FROM people ORDER BY age ASC LIMIT 100)
ORDER by name
```